# An interesting challenge for frontend developer

Tags: javascript, json

Found an interesting problem that I can’t solve.

1 condition. Only json can be changed!

I can’t fulfill one condition: `data.hasOwnProperty("\u{0030}")`

```
class JobSeeker {

    get data() {
            return '{"\\\\u{0030}": {}}';
    }

    }

    let data;
    console.assert(
        typeof (data = JSON.parse(new JobSeeker().data)) === "object"
        && data.hasOwnProperty("\u{0030}")
        && typeof Object.values(data)[0] === "object"
        && Boolean(data[+false]) === false
    );
```

What do you think will be the right json to suit all conditions?

Comment: `"\u{0030}"` is exactly the same string as `"0"`.

Comment: Yep, but how i need to change json, for console.assert = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you change the `data` getter to this:

```
get data() {
  return '{"\\u0030": null}';
}
```

That passes the first test because a valid JSON string is returned. The second test passes because "0" is the name of the only property in the object. The third test passes because `typeof null` is `"object"`. The fourth test passes because `Boolean(null)` is `false`.

I think it would also work if you change `\\u0030` to just plain `0`.